# Java concatenate 4 strings then truncate

Tags: java, concatenation, truncate

working on a Java issue

I've got 4 strings:
`s1`, `s2`, `s3`, `s4` that I must concatenate together into one.  If the subsequent resulting string is longer than 75 characters, I then need to truncate, but starting with `s1` and truncate the right most characters of that string until it fits into 75 with the other 3.  If I end up removing all the characters in `s1`, then proceed with `s2` truncation, again from the right most character, until `s2+s3+s4 <=75` and so on.

Any simple way to accomplish this?  I've been thinking of a while() loop but it gets pretty complicated when I'm checking `s1+s2+s3+s4` and then truncating one string at a time.

Anyone done something similar and have a good solution?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? And why weren't there any comments on the downvotes?

Comment: So are you taking letters off from right to left within each string s1, s2, etc, until the string fits within 75?

Answer (score 0):

You need to operate not with strings but with its length.

1. Get sum of length of all strings
2. Check which string need to truncate
3. Get sum beginning from truncated string.

Answer (score 0):

Add up the lengths of the strings.
If the result is greater than 75, calculate the number of chars to truncate.
Truncate the first string until you either truncated the correct number of chars, or the first string is empty.
In the later case repeat with string 2 and so on.
After that concatenate the resulting strings.

Now you just need to translate the prose into java code :-)

Comment: May be just subtract length of the first string form number of chars to truncate ;)

Comment: yeah, thats prolly what i would have done, but i'm not here to do his compsci homework for him. That's why i only wrote prose.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1, s2, s3, s4;

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(s1);
list.add(s2);
list.add(s3);
list.add(s4);

int len = 0;
for(String s : list)
    len += s.length();

if(len > 75)
{
    int diff = len - 75;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size() && diff > 0; i++) {
        String s = list.get(i);
        int len = s.length();
        if(len < diff)
            list.set(i, null);
        else {
            s = s.subString(0, s.length() - diff);
            list.set(i, s);
        }
        diff -= len;
    }
}

String result = "";
for(String s : list) {
    if(s != null) {
        // concat ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.